# Filtering function not returning filtered df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function like this:

```
sub_set <- function(var) {
    varname <- enquo(var)
    dict <- filter(dictionary, var == !!varname)
    return(dict)
}
dict <- sub_set(Age)
```

This does not work as it returns:

Error in ~Age : object 'Age' not found

If I call the function as:

```
dict <- sub_set("Age")
```

It works, however I need to call it without quotes as this functions is part of a bigger function that also uses (var), and quoting it breaks other parts of the function. So how can I make it to work by passing the parameter unquoted?

Regards,

Comment: What are you trying to do with `var == !!varname`, it looks like you're testing the column against itself? Example data and output would be helpful here to understand what's going on.

Comment: var is the column's name so what I want it to filter that column if it's values are "Age". In the df the var column is type string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enexpr` to convert `var` to a `name` class object and then `as_string` to a character string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

sub_set <- function(var) {
    varname <- as_string(enexpr(var))
    dict <- filter(dictionary, var == !!varname)
    return(dict)
}

dictionary <- data.frame(var = c("Age", "x"), var2 = 1:2) # test data
dict <- sub_set(Age)
dict
##   var var2
## 1 Age    1
```

### Base R

This could also be done readily in base R:

```
sub_set_base <- function(var) {
   varname <- deparse(substitute(var))
   subset(dictionary, var == varname)
}
sub_set_base(Age)
##   var var2
## 1 Age    1
```

### Formula

Another base R design not involving passing a character string would be to pass a formula:

```
sub_set_fo <- function(fo) {
   subset(dictionary, var == all.vars(fo))
}
sub_set_fo(~Age)
##   var var2
## 1 Age    1
```

Comment: It works as a standalone function... However if nested into a second function filtering does not work:    

second_func <- function(var) {
    dict <- sub_set(var)
}
second_func(var = Age)

Fails, I guess I'm struggling with understanding how functions deal with parameters. Again this is a simple example of a larger function but calling this second function seems to try to filter on "var" instead of "Age" and returns and empty df

Comment: `second_func` should be `second_func <- function(var) { 
  var <- enexpr(var); sub_set(!!var) 
}; second_func(var = Age)` .